# Oauthでの認証をRspecの統合テストで確認する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, oauth

Railsでログイン管理にFacebookのOAuthでの認証を使っているのですが、それに対するテストを書くことがうまくできず躓いています。ネット上にいくつか情報はあったのですが古いものも錯綜しておりどれに従えば良いのかわかりませんでした。

出来る所までやったのを書かせてもらいますと

#### spec/support/omniauth.rb

```
def set_omniauth
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook, {uid: '123545', name: 'foo bar'})
end
```

#### spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'authentication' do
  before do
    set_omniauth
    Rails.application.env_config["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user] 
    Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
    visit '/users/auth/facebook?user_type=host'
  end
  it 'Facebookから承認OK' do
    expect(page).to have_content 'Facebook から承認されました。'
  end
end
```

としているのですが、テストには以下のエラーで失敗します。

```
expected #has_content?("Facebook から承認されました。") to return true, got false
```

`spec/spec_helper.rb`で`add_mock`を使うサンプルなどもありましたが
公式のWikiと
https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

こちらのサイトを参考に行いました。
http://cookieshq.co.uk/posts/how-to-test-facebook-login-using-devise-omniauth-rspec-and-capybara/

どこを直せば正しくテストできるでしょうか？

### 追記

バージョン情報
rails (4.1.6)
rspec (3.3.0)
omniauth (1.2.2)
omniauth-facebook (2.0.0)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.2.0)
devise (3.4.1)

#### app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController <

```
Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    user_type = request.env["omniauth.params"]["user_type"]
    auth_info = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth_info, user_type)
    # 略
  end
end
```

#### app/models/user.rb

```
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, user_type)
    # 略
    User.new(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid,
             token: auth.credentials.token, authable_type: authable_type)
  end
```

Comment: RSpec、Devise、Omniauth、Railsのバージョンを教えてください。request specにvisitが登場しているので、もしかしてRSpec 2系かな？と思ったりしています。

Comment: それと、OmniAuthのコールバックを処理するコントローラのコードも見たいです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。もう一度コントローラのコードを確認していくと原因がわかりました。

Comment: `auth.credentials.token` と `request.env["omniauth.params"]["user_type"]` を使っていたのでそれぞれのためのmockを使うと正常にテストをパスできました。

Comment: それと `add_mock`で `:facebook`を作っているのに、読み込む時に間違えて`:twitter`を使っていました。

Comment: なるほどー。解決したのであれば、自分で回答を書き込んで自己承認してしまうのが良いと思います！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コントローラーとモデルで使っている`auth`と request の環境変数の情報が不足していたのが原因だったので

#### spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb

```
  before do
    # ~ 
    Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.params"] = {'user_type' => 'host'}
    # ~
  end
```

#### spec/support/omniauth.rb

```
  OmniAuth.config.add_mock(:facebook,
                           {'uid' => '123545',
                            'name' => 'foo bar',
                            'credentials' => {
                                'token' => 'mock_token',
                                'secret' => 'mock_secret'
                            }
                           }
  )
```

と必要なmockを作成することで解決しました。